# Those or these?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

"Like as in Python, operators can be overloaded and likes as in Python overloading is done by defining special functions."

Then:

"In D all those special functions start with `op` followed by a capital letter." or "In D all these special functions start with `op` followed by a capital letter."?

Those or these?

(D is a name of a programming language.)

Comment: 'these' and 'those' - both plural - differ in the only sense that the word 'these' refers to nearer and 'those' refers to things farther.  Thus, either of this should be fine, and the author has to take a call on whether it refers to nearby things or those farther.  You may consider reviewing it as "In D, all the special functions.....", whereby 'the' replaces these/ those.

Comment: like as an Python?? What does that mean?

Comment: @Lambie "Python" is the name of a programming language.

Comment: I know what Python is That is not my question.  I don't know what the bolded parts mean: "**Like as in Python,** operators can be overloaded and **likes as in Python overloading [etc.]**"

Comment: @Lambie I mean that overloading of operators in D is similar to overloading of operators in Python.

Comment: So that is what you should have said:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those = plural of that
These = plural of this

The two words differ only in the sense that 'these' refers to nearer things and 'those' refers to farther things. The author has to make the call on which they prefer, especially with abstract concepts.

For this sentence, I'd recommend omitting both:

> In D, all special functions start with op followed by a capital letter.

Or even omitting "all" (although you may prefer to leave it in).

> Special functions start with op followed by a capital letter.

"Like" and "as" mean something similar, so you don't need both.

> As in Python, operators can be overloaded and [as in Python] overloading is done by defining special functions.

The above parenthetical is meant to indicate those words are optional (although, you may prefer to leave them in).